# sql to set an xml value

Tags: sql, mysql, xml

I'm a novice in mySql.
I'm trying to replace a value in the xml column of my table.

my select method works.

```
SELECT * FROM `comics` WHERE ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber') = 6
```

my replace method doesn't.  I've been searching for the correct syntax for a bit now...

```
SET xml.modify(
replace value of ('comic/pageNumber') with 5
)
```

some background:

this situation comes up when i delete a comic page.

it leaves a gap in the page numbers, after which i would either:

iterate through all the comics and remove any gaps in the page numbers.

or

iterate through all comics with pageNumber larger than the deleted page, and reduce their pageNumber by 1.

Comment: Can you at least post 1 XML fragment representing a value in the xml column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
UPDATE comics 
SET xml = UpdateXML(xml,'comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>5</pageNumber>')
WHERE ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber') = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested on MySQL version 5.1

```
UPDATE `comics`
SET xml = UpdateXML(xml, 
                'comic/pageNumber', 
                concat('<pageNumber>',(ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber')+1),'</pageNumber>'))
WHERE ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber') >= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better off actually storing the fields in the table, rather than a single field with xml in it. Then the following would work. Otherwise there's not much point using a relational database at all.

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM `comics` 
    WHERE `comicID` = :id AND `pageNumber` = :page;
UPDATE `comics` SET `pageNumber` = `pageNumber` - 1 
    WHERE `comicID` = :id AND `pageNumber` > :page;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: sorry, I'm very passionate about storing it all in xml.

Comment: @SketchBookGames - Don't use MySQL then.