# sql setting xml property through a loop

Tags: sql, xml, for-loop

trying desperately to combine 2 simple answers into specifically what i need.

[sql loop and set properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940368/sql-loop-and-set-properties)

[sql to set an xml value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939901/sql-to-set-an-xml-value)

```
SET @I := 0;
SELECT *,
@I := @I + 1
SET xml = UpdateXML(xml,'comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>'.@I.'</pageNumber>')
FROM `comics`
ORDER BY ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber')+100000 ASC
```

this is as close as i have come,  i know the SELECT / ORDER BY works separate from trying to SET the xml property.

> side note: the +100000 is a work
>   around to treat the value as numeric
>   for sorting.  otherwise 11 < 2  but
>   100011 > 100002

i have also tried this

```
SET @I := 0;
UPDATE comics,
@I := @I + 1 AS newPageNumber
SET xml = UpdateXML(xml,'comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>'.@I.'</pageNumber>')
WHERE 1
ORDER BY ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber')+100000 ASC
```

i think i just don't know how to combine the SELECT and UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE comics
inner join (
  select c.id, @row:=@row+1 rownum
  from (select @row:=0) X cross join comics c
  ORDER BY ExtractValue(xml,'comic/pageNumber')*1.0) Y on Y.id=comics.id
SET xml = UpdateXML(xml, 
                'comic/pageNumber', 
                concat('<pageNumber>',Y.rownum,'</pageNumber>'))
;
```

Based on this test schema and data

```
create table comics (id int auto_increment primary key, xml text);
insert comics select null, '<comic><name>test1</name><pageNumber>7</pageNumber><content>page 5 con</content></comic>';
insert comics select null, '<comic><name>test1</name><pageNumber>3</pageNumber><content>page 6 con</content></comic>';
insert comics select null, '<comic><name>test1</name><pageNumber>5</pageNumber><content>page 7 con</content></comic>';
```